# Serializing Unserializable Python Objects Using Cython Pointers

Tags: python, serialization, multiprocessing, cython, cpython

I've been developing a Python debugger for the past 4 years (off and on) which has been extremely useful in helping me debug complicated Python code. The debugger acts like a program trace, allowing me to see everything my program does. It does this through the use of what amounts to a set of print statements.

For example, the following Python code:

```
if(x == True):
    Trace.If("User has enabled 'x'")

    n = Trace.Variable(n + x + y)

else:
    Trace.Else("User has not enabled anything")

    pass
```

Would output the following to a log file or database (assuming the 'if' statement condition was satisfied):

```
Counter - Timestamp - Filename - Function - Line of Code - If - User has enabled 'x'
Counter - Timestamp - Filename - Function - Line of Code - Variable - n = 13
```

An old version of my debugger performed every trace operation in the primary process/thread (associated with the program which my debugger was tracing). Though this wasn't a problem for applications which weren't timing critical, programs which were could not be properly traced. Because of this, I began work on a multi-threaded version of my Python debugger (for about 1 year). Though the speed improvements from going to a single threaded version of my debugging library, to a multi-threaded version of my debugging library helped a lot (as a lot of my library was I/O heavy), it wasn't enough for certain time critical Python applications.

I then began work on a multi-processing version of my debugging library (for about 0.5 years) and got everything to work, except for debugging statements related to the analysis of Python objects. For example, the following:

```
n = Trace.Variable(...some Python object...)
```

... will attempt to analyze the Python object, returning what amounts to a serialized version of the Python object in question. For example, the following code:

```
testABC = Trace.Variable([1, 2, [3, 4, {'Bacon': 0, 'Ham': 1, 'Cheese': 2, 'Eggs': 3456}]])
```

...will output the following trace/debugging data:

```
Counter - Timestamp - Filename - Function - Line of Code - Variable - testABC : (list) - [0] : (integer) - 1, [1] : (integer) - 2, [2] : (list) - [2][0] : (integer) - 3, [2][1] : (integer) - 4, [2][2] : (dictionary) - [2][2]{Bacon} : (integer) - 0, [2][2]{Ham} : (integer) - 1, [2][2]{Cheese} : (integer) - 2 and [2][2]{Eggs} : (integer) - 3456
```

Unfortunately, the portion of the library which handles the analysis of Python objects can be slow (depending on the Python object being analyzed). In order to prevent slowdowns in the main execution process/thread, I attempt to analyze Python objects in a separate Python process. The problem with this is that certain Python objects cannot be serialized (e.g. frame or inspect).

I've tried every type of serialization library (e.g. Pickle, Dill, etc.) as well as distributed computing library (e.g. ExecNet, RPyC, etc), but am not able to pass unserializeable Python objects to a separate process. The reason this is a problem, is that my Python debugging library is aimed at debugging/tracing any and all Python scripts. If a script happens to analyze an unserializable Python object, I need to perform the analysis of that Python object in the main execution process/thread (which as mentioned before, can be very slow).

I've looked at using Python interpreters which allow me to disable the GIL (global interpreter lock), in hopes of performing this costly analysis in a separate/concurrent thread. Interpreters such as Jython or IronPython currently only support Python 2.7 (which is a problem, as my library debugs Python 3.0+ scripts). I've also looked at interpreters which can speed up Python execution (in hopes of reducing the cost of performing costly analysis in the main process/thread), such as PyPy, but the main issue I have with PyPy is that its support for Windows (and Python 3 to an extent), seems tenuous. Plus the requirement that all libraries be reinstalled for PyPy is a problem as well (especially considering that not all Python libraries are fully supported - though I'm sure they're working on it).

With all that said, I had one last solution I was hoping to try out. Before doing so, I was hoping to go over the solution with someone on the Stack Overflow forum before coding it (as I'm not sure it will work). The pseudo code for the solution is the following:

```
1. Process 1 - Passes Python object (to be analyzed) to a Cython function.

2. Process 1 - Cython function stores Python object in memory and returns the memory address of the Python object.

3. Process 1 - Passes memory address of Python object (stored by Cython function) to a separate Python process (Process 2).

4. Process 2 - Receives memory address of Python object (stored by Cython function from Process 1) and passes the address to a Cython function.

5. Process 2 - Cython function pulls the Cython object pointing to the memory address, and returns a proxy of the original object.

6. Process 2 - Analyzes the Python object (returned by Cython function).
```

Question 1 - Is this possible (given that Python by itself, does not support passing objects by reference to another process)?

Question 2 - If so, will Python's garbage collector free the object as soon as I exit the Cython function (from step 2), or will it remain in memory (assuming that Cython relies on the programmer to free memory - just like in C)?

Question 3 - Will step 5 return a Python object, or will I have to convert the C object to a Python object (if so, how would I do this)?

Apologies for the long question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please take a look at [ask]. Right your question is too long and consists of multiple questions which are probably too broad.

Comment: I don't think one process can normally read another processes' memory, and I don't think Cython solves that. It also doesn't really have any special access to a generic Python object beyond what Python does (and you could get an address of a Python interest with ctypes I too I think). I'm reluctant to say "you can't do it" but I think you've just pushed all your issues to a hypothetical Cython layer...